# Generator evaluation difference between Python 2.x and Python 3.x

Tags: python

Test code could be listed below.

In Python 2.7.8, this code below caused my machine crashed.

```py
for row, current_char in zip(cycle(chain(pattern, pattern[::-1][1:][:-1])), count()):
    print row, current_char
    if current_char >= 14:
        break
```

While in Python 3.2.5.1, the code below works fine.

```py
for row, current_char in zip(cycle(chain(pattern, pattern[::-1][1:][:-1])), count()):
    print(row, current_char)
    if current_char >= 14:
        break
```

Result is

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
1 3
0 4
1 5
2 6
1 7
0 8
1 9
2 10
1 11
0 12
1 13
2 14
```

Is there anyone knowing the reason? Thanks

Comment: `zip` in Python 2 will (try to) build the whole list up-front; use `itertools.izip` instead. See https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists Also, you can combine your slices: `[-2:0:-1]`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks a lot, you got my point! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip` returns an iterator in Python 3, but a list in Python 2. `itertools.count` and `itertools.cycle` are both infinite generators, thus `zip`ping them together produces an "infinite" list.

As others already mentioned, you should use `itertools.izip` instead (Python 2 only).

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, `zip` like most other "functional" elements in the global namespace, returns a `list`, meaning it evaluates everything at once. In Python 3 this will be a generator, evaluated on demand and thus needing less memory (although the output you provided doesn't look like memory would be a problem).

Comment: Well you hit first :)